# Question on Norm inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

If $\|Gx\| \leq M \|x\|$, then why we can say that $\|G \| \leq M$ for all $x$? Here, M is a finite number, and we are in a normed linear space using the operator norm.

Thank you!

Comment: You can say $\|G\| \le M$, irregardless (:-)) of $x$. If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in X$ then $\sup_{x \in X} f(x) \le \sup_{x \in X} g(x) $

Comment: Because $\|G\|=\sup_{x\ne 0}\dfrac{\|Gx\|}{\|x\|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the set $\{\frac{||Gx||}{||x||}:\, x \neq 0\}$. This set is bounded above by $M$.  Then $||G||$, by definition, is the supremum of this set. The least upper bound must be less than or  equal to all upper bounds.